# How to report AppKit bug I can't reproduce but have dozens of reports (NSControlTrackMouse)

Tags: macos, appkit, macos-catalina, nsdatepicker

Since macOS Catalina I started to get report I can't reproduce but I know where is it crashing.
Register `rsi` has following selector in memory:

```
_controlStopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp:
```

SEGV_MAPERR has address `0x000059b575cd55f8` which is a result of `0x000059b575cd55e0+0x18`

```
AppKit where it crashes:
if (*(int8_t *)(var_90 + 0x18) != 0x0) {  
                            [r14 _controlStopTracking:r15 at:sign_extend_64(*(int8_t *)(var_70 + 0x18)) inView:r8 mouseIsUp:r9];  
                    }
```

[image]

[image]

Reports are coming from multiple systems/languages and I can't simulate the crash.
How to report this or what can I do more (debugging)?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV  
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x59b575cd55f8  
Crashed Thread:  0  


Thread 0 Crashed:  
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff64e2501d objc_msgSend + 29  
1   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c098af0 NSControlTrackMouse + 1491  
2   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c0984f4 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 129  
3   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c5d92b5 -[NSStepperCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 161  
4   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c3c86c4 -[NSDatePickerCell(NSTextFieldWithStepperDatePickerInternal) _textFieldWithStepperTrackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 391  
5   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c097733 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 747  
6   AppKit                               0x00007fff2c095b0d -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 4906  
7   AppKit                               0x00007fff2bfffc5c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2611  
8   AppKit                               0x00007fff2bfff005 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 348  
9   AppKit                               0x00007fff2bffd37c -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 351  
10  AppKit                               0x00007fff2be490cf -[NSApplication run] + 706  
11  AppKit                               0x00007fff2be1b465 NSApplicationMain + 776  
12  Dynaper                              0x00000001071d9199 main (receigen.h:5142)  
13  libdyld.dylib                        0x00007fff6619f7fd start + 0  
Thread 0 crashed with x86_64 Thread State:  
rflags: 0x0000000000010202    rax: 0x00007ffee8a765e8    rdi: 0x00006000018e55e0    r14: 0x00006000018e55e0  
   rsi: 0x00007fff2cadb39d     r8: 0x0000000000000091    rdx: 0x00007f9e6cd39f10    r10: 0x000059b575cd55e0  
    cs: 0x000000000000002b     fs: 0x0000000000000000     r9: 0x00000000000007fb    r15: 0x00007f9e6cd39f10  
   rbx: 0x0000000000000000    r11: 0x00007fff2cadb39d    rip: 0x00007fff64e2501d    rbp: 0x00007ffee8a766b0  
    gs: 0x0000000000000000    rsp: 0x00007ffee8a76468    r12: 0x000060000088dd40    rcx: 0x0000000000000000  
   r13: 0x00006000018e45b0
```

Comment: Can you talk to any user who has experienced this crash and asked them what they were generally doing?

Comment: @seth it's anonymous crash report. More than 40 unique crash reports but no user has complained as it seems as a random crash. This is why I can't simulate it.